# Java Application Hosting

Tags: java, jboss, hosting, glassfish

I've made a webapplication which runs on glassfish v3 on my computer. It's not a big application and i am not expecting a lot of traffic. All the hosts supporting glassfish is very expensive (about $40 a month) which is way to much at least in the beginning. I have found that it is cheaper on servers which has JBoss or Tomcat but will my application work on these servers? My application uses jsf 2.0 and hibernate. In case that it can be done will there be any disadvantages and can you guide me to a place where I can read about how this can be done or maybe even help me do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy a VPS(virtual private server) and install whatever you want(java,mysql,tomcat, etc):

- http://www.mediatemple.net/webhosting/ve/pricing.php
- http://www.linode.com
- http://www.slicehost.com

and so on, you can find even a cheaper one if you want it just for development/testing. The ones above are reliable hosting providers and you can use them as production servers.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with [eApps](http://www.eapps.com/) in the past for a small Java application and was very pleased with them. They specialize in Java hosting, which I found to be helpful when it came to configuring SSL certs and such. You are right, though. In general, Java hosting is more expensive than typical LAMP hosting. This is because most quality Java hosting services offer a separate JVM to each customer, which gives you more control but also consumes more resources.

By the way, I don't work for eApps and have no commercial interest in them.

Answer (score 0):

The only ones I know offering free application hosting are DreamHost and Google App Engine. They don't support "directly" technologies in question though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is possible to run JSF 2.0 applications on the Google Application Engine with a bit of elbow grease.  This might be exactly what you need initially for free.

http://java.dzone.com/news/jsf2-configuration-google-app

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Glassfish but you can run Tomcat on Amazon AWS EC2 'Micro-tier' server which is free for 12 months when you signup, it is then easy to scale up when you need

Comment: Seeing as those are root-servers(?), it should be easy to set up glassfish instead of Tomcat, yes.